# Custom error page in traefik2 with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I want to setup custom error pages for my traefik.
I have setup IpWhitelist (https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/ipwhitelist/) middleware which works fine. but in case of failure it shows standard error page "Forbidden". I want to replace it with custom error page.

I've added another middleware Errors (https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/errorpages/)
which works in case of 404 I can see the custom error page. but in case of Ipwhitelist failure it still shows standard "Forbidden"(403) page and not the custom error page. I've setup range of 400-405

I think either of one middleware is working or I'm doing something wrong.
I also want to configure Errors middleware globally so that i dont have to specify on each and every IngressRouts I configure on my environment.

traefik-error service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefikerror
  namespace: namespacename
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefikerror
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: traefikerror
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefikerror
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefikerror
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: traefikerror
        image: imageId
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

middleware

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: traefikerror
spec:
  errors:
    status:
      - 400-405
    query: /test.html
    service:
      name: traefikerror
      port: 80
```

and Setting this middleware in the IngressRoute.

Comment: did you try this https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/chain/ ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla : nope but looks good option I will try with that :)